# Is there a running app without cloud and with heart beat (heartrate) sensors connectability

Tags: android, privacy, health, bluetooth

I am looking for an Android running app that keeps my data local and doesn't share it with any cloud/server.

Also it should support Bluetooth Smart Heartbeat Sensors (chest belt).

Additional points for a data export to e.g. `.json`

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! While waiting for good recommendations, be welcome to check with [my corresponding app listing](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/sport_fitness#group_1084). I've heard RunnerUp (at the end of that list) or ForRunners should be quite good. Assuming you ask because of privacy concerns: avoid those with "monitor symbols" (tracking), concentrate on those with "yellow stars" (clean/no tracking modules found). The latter are most often from F-Droid, where those "tracking modules" are off-limits ;)